# NLTK add sections to corpus

Tags: python, nltk

I am going to process scientific papers using nltk.

To begin with, I would like to store the raw text of the papers as text files.
The text file would have a few sections, like this:

paper-1.txt:

```
Abstract
[abstract here] 

Introduction
[introduction here]

Body
[body here]
```

In the code, I would like to do something like this:

```
abstracts = nltk.SectionCorpusReader(root=..., section='abstract') # read abstracts only
full = nltk.SectionCorpusReader(root=..., section='full')          # read whole documents
```

I cannot figure out which corpus property to use to denote the sections. I have tried to divide the papers into multiple files: paper-1-abstract.txt, paper-1-intro.txt, etc. and use the PlaintextCorpusReader. This doesn't work well - you get multiple nltk documents per one real document.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: XMLCorpusReader is good for structured documents. It shouldn't be hard to design a simple XML envelope for your document structure. But you may have to play around a bit to get it to read multiple files. Perhaps CHILDESCorpusReader can serve as an example.

Comment: A better fit might be the CategorizedCorpusReader (http://nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext.CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader).